# Erlang syntax - Building an Intellij IDEA language support plugin for Erlang

Tags: erlang, bnf, ebnf

I'm looking to create an Intellij IDEA language support plugin for Erlang.

The first and biggest problem I've had is in making the JFlex Erlang syntax definition.

Does anyone know where can I get the EBNF or BNF for Erlang?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not go [straight to the source](http://www.erlang.org/doc.html)?  The [Erlang 4.7 specification](http://www.erlang.org/download/erl_spec47.ps.gz) lists productions in a grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `lib/compiler/src/core_parse.yrl` in the otp source distribution.